# Excel file import, Comma as delimiter

Tags: excel, vba

Hi have been working on a method to import a text file into a specified worksheet, within a master workbook. Up until recently the file used Tab as the delimiter, which I was able to specify like so:
workbooks.open fileToOpen,,,,,,,,vbtab

now the file has switched to the use of a comma, which i have tried to specify in the line above but have been unable to get to work.  im fairly new at this so not sure what my options. is there a way that I can get the code to identify the delimiter and convert based on that?

any help appreciated

copy of code :

```
Sub Multi_T_Import()

Dim fileToOpen, closeWorkbook, searchchar, sName As String
Dim chkFile, fileImport As Integer
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long



searchchar = "\"
'Turn off any prompts

MsgBox "Please Select Multi Token Data File" & vbNewLine & "MULTI TOKEN DATA IMPORT"

'Select the file to import
fileToOpen = Application _
.GetOpenFilename("txt Files (*.txt), *.txt")



'Option to import a different fileIf fileToOpen <> False Then
If fileToOpen <> False Then
    fileImport = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to import " & fileToOpen, vbYesNo)
    If fileImport = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Import of " & fileToOpen & " has been aborted"
         
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

If fileImport = False Then Exit Sub


Workbooks.Open fileToOpen

   
Sheets.Select
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

FinalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

FinalRow = FinalRow + 1
Range("A1:V" & FinalRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows(MasterFileName).Activate
Sheets("Multi_Token_Report").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'Columns("Q").Cut
'Columns("A").Insert


closeWorkbook = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, searchchar) + 1)
Workbooks(closeWorkbook).Close SaveChanges:=False


Dim oFS As Object
    
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Range("X1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = oFS.GetFile(fileToOpen).DateLastModified

    Set oFS = Nothing
    
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a build-in function for separating things like comma, tab or else.
After you load in txt, it use the first column to store data. So, simply select all data on A column and use the build in function.

in VBA code, it is something like this, [ after opening txt in excel ]

```
Workbooks(NewWB).Sheets(1).Range("A1").EntireColumn.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), Comma:=True
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSOlZ.png)